# Preparing food on Shabbos for Bein Hashmoshos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, evening-night, hachana-prep-for-weekday

I have asked in a different [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22127/cooking-on-yom-tov-for-bein-hashmoshos) for the citation to the Pri Megadim that I've heard says it's [ossur](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to cook on yom tov for the purpose of eating the food Bein Hashmoshos.

Although a [makor](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1395) for that hasn't been posted yet, I'd like to ask another question in that regard (assuming that the Pri Megadim says in fact what I think he says).

Would it be [muter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) on Shabbos to prepare a food that would be eaten bein hashmoshos, or would this be a problem of "preparing" on Shabbos for the weekday (based on the fact that bein hashmoshos is "sofek lyleh" (possibly night) and is perhaps already the next day, so that it would turn out that the person prepared the food specifically for the next day)? I'm of course speaking of a case where the person's whole intention was to make the food to specifically eat it during the time of bein hashmoshos (if it would be part of the 3rd official Shabbos meal then obviously that would be a different story).

Comment: *May* you begin to eat bein hashmoshot on Shabbas?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - I don't know, presumably not. But let's say it's a case that you want to give the food to children (which however could be answered if it's being done for a child then certainly we wouldn't be worried about issues of preparing on Shabbos for weekday.) At least your intention when making the food is that it should be for bein hoshmoshos

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman You can if you made havdala at plag.

Comment: Yehoshua, can you clarify more explicitly in the question which bein hashemashot of Shabbat you're referring to?

Comment: @msh210 Hachana can also be prep from Shabbat to Yom Tov or vice-versa (or maybe even Yom Tov to another Yom Tov in the case of Rosh HaShana; also Yom Tov to Chol HaMoed depending how you want to categorize that).

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes. Tag names are limited to 25 characters.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, I was thinking to just make it [tag:hachana-preparation].

Comment: @DoubleAA [let's continue this conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6798498#6798498).

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought Rosh Hashana was the one yom tov where we *were* allowed to cook for the second day? Or do I have it backwards?

Comment: @DoubleAA "You can if you made havdala at plag." - Do you mean making havdala before Shabbos ends? Is this ever done?

Comment: @sah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57268/759 I heard of it happening once in a community expecting a hurricane to hit in a couple hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biur Halacha (503:1 "Beyom Tov") writes that it forbidden to prepare from before shkiya for after shkiya. Shmiras Shabbas Kehilchoso Chapter 28 footnote 168 quotes this with regards to Shabbos as well. (See there that he discusses preparing during Bein Hashmoshos for Bein Hashmoshos).