Saying Boruch Hamavdil before Birkas Hamazon
One who eats Seudah Shlishis on Shabbos and before saying Birkas Hamazon they said Baruch Hamavdil Bain Kodesh L'chol, do they still say Retzei in the Birkas Hamazon?

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80062/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82657/759

According to the Mishnah Berurah (188:32):

וכיון שהתחלת הסעודה היה מבעוד יום כבר נתחייב להזכיר מעין המאורע. וע"כ אפילו נמשך זמן רב בלילה לא נפקע חיובו. וכתבו האחרונים דאם התפלל מעריב קודם בהמ"ז שוב אינו מזכיר של שבת בבהמ"ז דמחזי כסתרי אהדדי:


Since the beginning of the meal was during the day, he was already obligated to mention the occasion. Therefore, even if [the meal] extended way into the night, this obligation does not leave. The Acharonim write that if he davened maariv before saying birkas hamazon, he no longer says Retzeh in birkas hamazon as it looks like a contradiction.

Based on this reasoning, the same is true if he made havdalah or any other action demonstrating that it is no longer Shabbos.

Not all תרתי דסתרי are alike. MB 491:1 says one should not eat chometz in a pesach meal that extends through the end of yom tov because it would appear to contradict the recital of יעלה ויבוא, but it's implied one should still say it after the fact.

@shmosel Thanks. It seems I can no longer delete my answer since it has been accepted, but I would if I could :)

Shulchan Aruch HaRav O"C 188:17 says that although one wouldn't say Retzeh after maariv or a proper havdalah, it's questionable whether just saying Hamavdil would fall into the same category. However, since there are opinions that hold we never say it after nightfall, it's best to skip it in this scenario:

וְאִם אָמַר "הַמַּבְדִּיל בֵּין קֹדֶשׁ לְחֹל" בִּלְבַד בְּלֹא כּוֹס,
כְּמוֹ שֶׁיִּתְבָּאֵר בְּסִימָן רצ"ט – יֵשׁ לְהִסְתַּפֵּק... אִם
דִּינוֹ כְּהִתְפַּלֵּל עַרְבִית. וּלְפִיכָךְ, שֵׁב וְאַל תַּעֲשֶׂה
עָדִיף, שֶׁהֲרֵי יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁלְּעוֹלָם אֵינוֹ מַזְכִּיר שֶׁל
שַׁבָּת אַחַר שֶׁיָּצָא הַיּוֹם

